# Is it possible to extract persistence unit configuration information at runtime?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm developing an application (Java EE using JPA/Hibernate, Servlet, JSP, no framework) and I found that in a specific module it is easier to implement native SQL (instead of using ORM direct solution). No problem at all, but I want it to make dynamically, i.e: I want my code to be bullet-proof in case I change the persistence provider.

I want to do something like:

```
MySpecificQueryMakerInterface myQueryMaker = new MySpecificQueryMakerFactory(EntityManager.getPersistenceUnit().getProvider());
```

And in the `MySpecificQueryMakerFactory,` create the adequate class that will execute the native SQL for the current database I'm using. Doing so, I will be able to create classes that will extend `MySpecificQueryMakerInterface` like `MyPostgresQueryMaker` or `MyOracleQueryMaker`, and I will only change the factory whenever I add a new specific database.

Is there a way to get the information of the Persistence Unit / Datasource using JPA/Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to specify a custom property (e.g. class name) in the persistence unit which you can access via [EntityManagerFactory#getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getProperties%28%29). You can get the factory via [EntityManager#getEntityManagerFactory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getEntityManagerFactory%28%29).